# Bitwise operators - precision

Tags: java, logic, bit-manipulation

Three questions that I seem to be stuck on:

1. Why is the code `x & ~077` better than this line of code `x & 0177700`.
   Would it be because there is less loss of precision?
2. Why is this code incorrect for setting bit 5 in a number?
   `num = num + 0x20`
   Would it be because we need to use logical or, `|`, not the `+`?
3. Why is this code `x & 0xFF` better than this line of code `(x << 24) >> 24`?
   The right expression could result in sign extension which changes the original int. I am sure that is correct from examples I have done.

Comment: (1) isn't better, and there is certainly no precision issue, assuming 'x' is a short, which you haven't confided. Why you would write either is a mystery to me: octal is for the birds. (2) What other reason would there be? (3) You've answered your own question, but it is also shorter.

Comment: Why was this closed? Certainly real questions. Voted to reopen.

Comment: I'm going to vote to reopen, but please ask only one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1, why is this code x & ~077 better than this line of code x & 0177700.

Because in the second one you are making assumptions on the length of the integer type of x

> 2, why is this code incorrect for setting bit 5 in a number? num = num + 0x20 Would it be because we need to use logical or, |, not the +?

yes! they are different operators.

Comment: Awesome, makes sense! One thing I didn't understand was problems that would occur when converting integers to floats or floats to integers, Would it be because when converting an int to a float, you are making an assumption? I am confused on why it would cause problems

Comment: @JamesCarter There's no problem with int to float, but there is a possible truncation in the reverse direction.

Comment: @EJP , correct me if i'm wrong, is it because we create the decimal formate which causes the truncation? Could you give me a case of precision loss based on the truncation?

Comment: @JamesCarter What decimal format? Possible truncation arises because the range of a float is much bigger than the range of an int.